# browser time out using domain name but not on local server

Tags: python-3.x, django

I require help in setting up the browser (Chrome) time-out session.

For example:-

1 am generating a report in real-time when I am generating it on the local server (127.0.0.1).  it is working without any issue and no time-out issue.

```
          But when I am trying that the same using domain name from a local PC and if it is taking more than 120 Sec to generate because of more data say 1000000 records in the report the page is getting expired or timeout.
```

How to fix this issue?

The development platform is Python, Django & PostgreSQL.

Comment: Either increase the server timeout (not recommended), or optimize the task you are running, or (eventually the most reasonable approach in a long run) would be to not run the task within the request but as a background task and keep checking with ajax requests if it finished.

Comment: Thanks, @yedpodtrzitko for the advice but it doesn't solve my problem